# Is the Authentication Scaffolding section while upgrading to laravel 5.3 mandatory?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am upgrading my laravel to 5.3 and I am at the Authentication Scaffolding section. Is that section mandatory to be done. My routes work fine without it anyway.

Secondly, is it necessary for me to split my route files like they have done in 5.3 in three separate files and then put them in to the routes folder? Or can I get by the old way of doing it by just using the routes.php file like earlier?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using their Authentication scaffolding it's probably wise that you do follow those instructions. I personally am not using it so I didn't bother with that. I don't think it will break your application if you leave them though.

With regards to splitting your routes into the separate files, I haven't actually seen anything in the upgrade guide documenting what to do in that regard. I don't think your application will break if you leave everything in your usual `routes.php` file as it is. However, if you do want to change to the new setup, make sure you update your [RouteServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) file to reflect the updates there (It's this file that `require`s the route files.